# How to use subprocess popen Python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Since `os.popen` is being replaced by `subprocess.popen`, I was wondering how would I convert

```
os.popen('swfdump /tmp/filename.swf/ -d')
```

to `subprocess.popen()`

I tried:

```
subprocess.Popen("swfdump /tmp/filename.swf -d")
subprocess.Popen("swfdump %s -d" % (filename))  # NOTE: filename is a variable
                                                # containing /tmp/filename.swf
```

But I guess I'm not properly writing this out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this a Windows Machine or Linux machine ?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` takes a list of arguments:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['swfdump', '/tmp/filename.swf', '-d'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

There's even a [section of the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3) devoted to helping users migrate from `os.popen` to `subprocess`.

Comment: @HansThen `shell=True` is **not** recommended.

Comment: Only when combined with __untrusted__ input. In this case you can use it just fine.

Comment: why is `shell=True` not recommended?

Comment: @HansThen "Just fine"? How do you know `filename` is not derived from user input?

Comment: @Lukas Graf Since it says so in the code. 
@Alex shell=True is considered a security risk when used to process untrusted data. A clever attacker can modify the input to access arbitrary system commands. E.g. by inputting `filename.swf; rm -rf /` for the value of filename. However, this is only a problem, when the contents of your argument to Popen is insecure.

Comment: @HansThen: It just says what an example value of `filename` is, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Lukas Graf From the code fragment I strongly doubt that was meant as an example value, to be filled by untrusted user supplied data. But I am prepared to call a truce on that item. My point was more that there is no reason not to use `shell=True` except when using __untrusted__ input. Simply stating that `shell=True` is not recommended is misleading.

Comment: @HansThen: Well, and I strongly doubt the OP has `/tmp/filename.swf` hardcoded in his application, but instead ends up with this string by doing path manipulation etc.., _possibly_ on user input. But besides that, `shell=True` has other disadvantages: You spawn an unnecessary shell process that simply isn't needed in this case, and quoting and escaping can get really tricky.

Comment: @HansThen: P.S. Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to get on your case here. It's just that you seem to be aware of the risks involved with `shell=True`, but any random user stumbling across this question might not be. That's why I think it's important to highlight that `shell=True` in fact isn't recommended, unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @LukasGraf, @HansThen: If `shell=True` was so harmful, it wouldn't be included in `subprocess.Popen()` as a keyword argument. There are security risks involved in executing untrusted user input and the benefit of using a `list` to hold the components of the command is that it escapes and properly quotes the arguments, which may include unwanted characters. `shell=True` can be used if you're literally translating Bash commands to Python (or, correct me if I'm wrong, piping command output as well).

Comment: @Blender Nobody said it was harmful - it's merely dangerous. But aside from that, your argument doesn't make sense at all. Many OS functions that the Python standard library exposes are potentially dangerous - take `shutil.rmtree` for example. But that has nothing to do with whether they are included in the stdlib or not. I believe the UNIX philosophy of _"Unix was not designed to stop its users from doing stupid things, as that would also stop them from doing clever things."_ also applies in large parts to Python.

Comment: @LukasGraf: I don't have an argument. I'm merely saying that using `shell=True` is discouraged when including arbitrary input. The documentation says: *For this reason, the use of `shell=True` is strongly discouraged in cases where the command string is constructed from external input*. Why give the command more chances to fail when you can give it less?

Comment: @Blender: I'm sorry, I don't get what you mean by your last sentence. As for your argument, I was referring to _"If shell=True was so harmful, it wouldn't be included"_. But either way, I think we all agree on the technical facts anyway ;)

Comment: shouldn't you be using `process.communicate()` rather than `process.stdout` to ensure that stderr is handled properly?

Comment: Can I split the full command (for example "cmd -x -y 777 -z home/blah") by space to create a valid list of inputs to subprocess.pOpen() ?

Answer (score 18):

In the recent Python version, `subprocess` has a big change. It offers a brand-new class `Popen` to handle `os.popen1|2|3|4`.

The new `subprocess.Popen()`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('ls -la', shell=True)
```

Its arguments:

```
subprocess.Popen(args, 
                bufsize=0, 
                executable=None, 
                stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, 
                preexec_fn=None, close_fds=False, 
                shell=False, 
                cwd=None, env=None, 
                universal_newlines=False, 
                startupinfo=None, 
                creationflags=0)
```

Simply put, the new `Popen` includes all the features which were split into 4 separate old `popen`.

The old `popen`:

```
Method  Arguments
popen   stdout
popen2  stdin, stdout
popen3  stdin, stdout, stderr
popen4  stdin, stdout and stderr
```

You could get more information in [Stack Abuse - Robert Robinson](https://stackabuse.com/pythons-os-and-subprocess-popen-commands/). Thank him for his devotion.

Answer (score 12):

Use [sh](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/), it'll make things a lot easier:

```
import sh
print sh.swfdump("/tmp/filename.swf", "-d")
```

Comment: sh, it's good, however it's not same with Popen of subprocess. sh is alike with call of subprocess.

Answer (score 12):

It may not be obvious how to break a shell command into a sequence of arguments, especially in complex cases. `shlex.split()` can do the correct tokenization for args (I'm using Blender's example of the call):

```
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
command = shlex.split('swfdump /tmp/filename.swf/ -d')
process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html