# Ubuntu/Python- How to call ubuntu commands and 3rd party applications through Python

Tags: python, ubuntu

Basically, I'm trying to navigate through directories and call a specific program (called `galfit`). The reason I navigate through the directories is because all of the files that I want to run through `galfit` are in that directory. However, there are dozens of files, and individually running each file through `galfit` would take far too long. On top of that, they take a while to process, so the overall process is incredibly slow.

Here's what the Ubuntu terminal code looks like:

```
vidur@vidur-VirtualBox:~$ cd Documents
vidur@vidur-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ cd XDF_Thumbnails_sci
vidur@vidur-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ ls
documents-export-2013-07-08  XDF_Images_Sci  XDF_Images_Wht  XDF_Thumbnails_Sci
vidur@vidur-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ cd XDF_Thumbnails_Sci
vidur@vidur-VirtualBox:~/Documents/XDF_Thumbnails_Sci$ ~/galfit galfit.feedme
```

`galfit.feedme` is the feedme file that I wish to process; however, there are about fifty files in total (with different names, of course!) that I wish to process.

So my question is, how do you approach that through Python? Eventually I'll be looping through all the files (and likely somehow auto-naming them, that's easy), but what's the process to get to the directory and then run `galfit`?

Comment: Have a look at the `os` module.

Comment: You can send shell commands though `os.system`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) for directory navigation. To execute a shell command use [os.system](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system). The example you posted could go something along the lines of:

```
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/XDF_Thumbnails_Sci'))
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == ".feedme":
        os.system("~/galfit %s" % file)
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Out of curiosity, what does "%s % file" do?

Comment: also, os.system() does execute other programs, but sooner or later subprocess.popen() might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python

Comment: It's C-style string formatting, as detailed [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). Technically though, it's deprecated since Python 3.1 and the recommended syntax is now [.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! Is there a method for simply running a command as is, like "~/galfit f105w0.feedme" instead of having to open a program or something? 

Sorry for the repeated questions, it's just that this is all very new and very fascinating to me.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to do something like this more natively, try shell scripts. The [Advanced BASH Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) could get you started.