# passing more than one variables to os.system in python

Tags: python, os.system

I want to pass two variables to the os.system() for example listing files in different format in specific directory like (ls -l testdirectory) in which both a switch and test directory are variable.
I know for single variable this one works:

`option=l
os.sytem('ls -%s' option)`

but I dont know how to pass two variables?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `os.system()` to begin with; use the much more flexible (and safer) `subprocess` module. (Your example won't work to begin with, either...)

Comment: @Wooble meh technically your right ... i still use os.system regularly though also ... its just simple if thats all you need and you definately control the input ...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python .

Comment: @Wooble I can't see any documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) that suggests security issues in using os.system. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @codaamok See e.g. [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) but it is also prominenetly mentioned in the `os.system` documentation, along with the recommendation to prefer the `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 24):

you are asking about string formating (since `os.system` takes a string, not a list of arguments)

```
cmd = "ls -{0} -{1}".format(var1,var2)
#or cmd = "{0} -{1} -{2}".format("ls","l","a")
os.system(cmd)
```

or

```
cmd = "ls -%s -%s"%(var1,var2)
```

or

```
cmd = "ls -"+var1+" -"+var2
```

Answer (score 11):

This, for example, works:

```
os.system('%s %s' % ('ls', '-l'))
```