# using tshark with variable in python

Tags: python, wireshark, tshark

I have large .pcap file for post processing. I am using tshark for it and I am able to get around with hard-coded values with os.system in python.

```
os.system("tshark -r file.pcap -T fields \
                 -R \"frame.number > 50 && wlan.da == 08:11:96:1e:e2:a4\" \
                 -e radiotap.mcs.index -e wlan.fc.retry\
                 -e radiotap.datarate > hp1.txt")
```

I want to find a better option to above - wherein I can use variables. 
example - Filename - variable , total frame count - variable , destination address - variable and so on

I checked few SO links [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101931/passing-more-than-one-variables-to-os-system-in-python) but it didnt help me get pass the hurdle.

Are there other options than using os.system to achieve above purpose ?

Comment: Why are the answers from the SO link you provided not good for you?

Comment: @pchaigno - My bad it works - wasnt using the information provided in link properly .. will close the question