# Executing python scripts sequentially using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, subprocess

I am using python's `subprocess` for executing scripts against a C code base. Concretely, I have a number of scripts that I run one by one against a single instantiation of a program. Here is what I want to do:

```
start process ABC

execute python scripts 01 against ABC and store output from ABC in file A

execute python scripts 02 against ABC and store output from ABC in file B

execute python scripts 03 against ABC and store output from ABC in file C
```

My current scheme with

```
myProcess = subprocess.Popen(PATH, BUFFSIZE, STDOUT= myFilePointer ...)
```

But this fails to yield return output from each execution of process ABC and only records output in case of script 01 and not the rest.

I have looked at [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3) and other [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python) but cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 cmd = subprocess.Popen("ABC %s" % command,
                    stdout=out,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 stdout, stderr = cmd.communicate()
 retcode = cmd.returncode
```

Use **command** parameter to pass command line argument to ABC. After execution of Popen output from ABC will be stored in **stdout**. Error that might occur are stored to **stderr**.