# Running an exe file in python - not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a crazy problem.
I have a cmd to run an exe file and it executes with no errors. The cmd in command prompt is

```
E:\project\cpp\myfirst.exe
```

I have to call this exe file within my python script. I use subprocess.call. But I get an error. The code and error is as follows

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('E:\\project\\cpp\\myfirst.exe')
```

The error i get is

```
ERROR: Could not open myfirst setup file
1
```

I couldnt find the solution. I also tried os.system call. But still the same error. can you guys help me.

NOTE: the exe file is generated from a cpp code

thanks

Comment: When you run it from cmd, do you run it from the same directory (i.e. just as `myfirst.exe`)?

Comment: Yeah. I run it from the same directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program seems to be seeking for some configuration file in the working directory, which is not always the same as the one where the executable is. Try instead:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('myfirst.exe', cwd=r'E:\project\cpp')
```

If you have written `myfirst.exe` yourself, consider changing the lookup logic so that it checks the executable's own directory.

Answer (score -1):

Under Linux I have always found the **popen** mechanism to be more reliable.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE process = Popen(['swfdump',
'/tmp/filename.swf', '-d'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) stdout, stderr =process.communicate()
```

Answer taken from

[How to use subprocess popen Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python)