# How to write a bash script which calls itself with python?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, sh

Can someone explain how this bash script works? The part I don't understand is `""":"`, what does this syntax mean in bash?

```
#!/bin/sh 

""":"

echo called by bash
exec python $0 ${1+"$@"}

"""

import sys
print 'called by python, args:',sys.argv[1:]
```

test running result:

```
$ ./callself.sh xx
called by bash
called by python, args: ['xx']


$ ./callself.sh
called by bash
called by python, args: []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's clever! **In Bash**, the `""":"` will be expanded into only `:`, which is the empty command (it doesn't do anything). So, the next few lines will be executed, leading to `exec`. At that point, Bash *ceases to exist*, and the file is re-read by Python (its name is `$0`), and the original arguments are forwarded.

The `${1+"$@"}` means: If `$1` is defined, pass as arguments `"$@"`, which are the original Bash script arguments. If `$1` is not defined, meaning Bash had no arguments, the result is empty, so nothing else is passed, not even the empty string.

**In Python**, the `"""` starts a multi-line string, which includes the Bash commands, and extends up to the closing `"""`. So Python will jump right below.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for [polyglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)), where you write multiple programing languages in a file and still make it valid.

**How is it valid in python**

```
""":"

echo called by bash
exec python $0 ${1+"$@"}

"""
```

This is a multiline docstring in python so python completely ignores it till the `import` line

**How is it valid in bash**

```
""":"

echo called by bash
exec python $0 ${1+"$@"}
```

The `exec` calls the same script using python interpreter and exits the script. So it will not execute the remaining syntactically wrong python statements.

Answer (score 0):

[What is the purpose of the : (colon) GNU Bash builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin)

Also, once exec is called, the rest of the code is not executed because exec replaces the shell with the program, in this case the python process. (http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/exec)