# How to setup the linux "hcitool lecup" from within a python script?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to read some sensor data from a wireless BLE IMU sensor into my Raspberry Pi 3B. I need to be able to read the data at 100Hz (10ms intervals). It appears that one of the aspects I need to configure is the polling interval of "hcitool lecup". Here are the two main things I am struggling:

1. How can I configure the command from my python script without having to run it from my terminal window?
2. What would be the correct way to configure the intervals to get 10Hz polling rate? Can I set the min and max intervals to be the same: `hcitool lecup -H handle -m 0x0008 -M 0x0008 -l 0000 -t 0x0064`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling subprocesses with python is best done with the `subprocess` module and the `Popen` method.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python) might be of help to you