# After python subprocess.popen return control to user

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin

I want to send some input (which depends on the programs output) but let the user have interactive control over the program after the input has been sent.  I am using

```
    p = subprocess.Popen(['./program'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

followed by a bunch of conditional p.stdin.write('...') and p.stdout.read(nBytes) statements.

How can I return the control (stdin / stdout) to the user as normal after this is done? I prefer python3 but would also be happy with python2 solutions.

Comment: possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python

Comment: Nope, not related. It is a different question about the same python module.