# (python 3) Auto-Conversion from .h264 to .mp4

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi, command, raspbian

I have a Python 3 code that is supposed to record video. Unfortunately, I do not want it in .h264, I need it to convert to .mp4. Using other StackOverflow threads as a template (specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python) one), I thought the easiest way to do this would have been to use `subprocess.Popen` to insert `MP4Box -add filename.h264 filename.mp4` into the terminal and have it do it for me automatically. Unfortunately, the Python script doesn't do anything and I don't get any error messages, so I don't know what's going wrong. The .h264 file appears in the folder I want it to, if I manually put in the command into the terminal the .mp4 appears, but when I just let it run nothing happens. The rest of the script works like a charm. The code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from gpiozero import Motor
from picamera import PiCamera
import subprocess
import os.path
import shlex
import datetime as dt
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()
pir = MotionSensor(4, 1, 100, .6, False)
motor = Motor(3,14) #first number is forwards, second is backwards
startupTime = 1
recordingTime = 1
collectionTime = 3
resetTime = 30



while True:
    sleep(startupTime) #delay a bit so installation can take place

    #wait for motion, then move the motor back and forth
    pir.wait_for_motion() 
    print("Motion Detected")
    #moves motor forward for 3 seconds at 25% speed
    motor.forward(.25)
    print("Strip Extending")
    sleep(3) 
    motor.stop()
    #leaves strip out for given amount of time
    print("Collecting Sample")
    sleep(collectionTime) 
    #moves motor backward for 3 seconds at 50% speed
    motor.backward(.5)
    print("Strip Retracting")
    sleep(3) 
    motor.stop()

    #Prep file for correct saving
    filename = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.h264") #saves file as a date
    save_path= "/home/pi/ANALYSIS"
    completed_video= os.path.join(save_path, filename)

    #Start recording
    camera.start_recording(completed_video) #starts recording and saves it as filename
    print("Camera Recording")
    camera.annotate_text = dt.datetime . now() . strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S")
    start=dt.datetime.now()

    #Keep recording until time runs out, annotate to make sure we have reference frame
    while (dt.datetime.now() - start).seconds < recordingTime: 
        camera.annotate_text = dt.datetime.now(). strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S")
        camera.wait_recording(.2)
    camera.stop_recording()

    #Conversion to usable file format
    print("Camera finished recording... Beginning Analysis")
    from subprocess import CalledProcessError
    command = shlex.split("MP4Box -add {} {}.mp4".format(completed_video, os.path.splitext(filename)[0]))
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        print('FAIL:\ncmd:{}\noutput:{}'.format(e.cmd, e.output))

    #starts detecting again after given time
    sleep(resetTime)
    print("Ready for next sample")
```

---

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):  
>
    File "/home/pi/Detector.py", line 62, in <module> output = 
      subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) 
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 620, in check_output raise 
      CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output) 
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: 
        Command '['MP4Box', '-add', '2017-07-11_15.34.49.h264.h264', '2017-07-11_15.34.49.h264.mp4']' 
>
Returned non-zero exit status 1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Comment**: 2017-07-11_15.34.49.h264.h264

Your Filepath/Filename is wrong, change to the following:

> **Note**: The `.mp4` is saved in to the Current Directory the Subprocess is executed,
>   the Directory the Python Script is started. This could be different as the `.h264` are saved!
>   Think about to change that also to be a absolute Path.

```
command = "MP4Box -add {} {}.mp4".format(completed_video, os.path.splitext(filename)[0])
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print('FAIL:\ncmd:{}\noutput:{}'.format(e.cmd, e.output))
```

---

> os.remove(path, *, dir_fd=None)
>
> Remove (delete) the file path.

---

> **Question**: I don't get any error messages, so I don't know what's going wrong.

Try the following:
To also capture standard error in the result, use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`:

```
command = shlex.split("MP4Box -add {f}.h264 {f}.mp4".format(f=filename))
output = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(output)
```

I assume you need `shell=True` as you dont give a Fullpath to `MP4Box` so a Shell Environment is needed to find `MP4Box`.

Comment: It says "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Detector.py", line 62, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 620, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['MP4Box', '-add', '2017-07-11_15.34.49.h264.h264', '2017-07-11_15.34.49.h264.mp4']' returned non-zero exit status 1"                                would I add the shell=True after the (f=filename) and after a comma too?

Comment: Ok, I edited it with the most recent error and my updated .py script. I also tried the old code using a different filename so the .h264 didn't repeat, but to no vail.

Comment: It says "No module name 'CalledProcessError'", do I have to import it from another module?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, my bad. I really appreciate your help, you're amazing! I updated with the most recent code and error, I think it's very close now.

Comment: YES!!!! IT WORKED! Thank you so much, I'd been going crazy for a week. There's an extra parentheses but apart from that your code is gold.