# How to write command using subprocess in python3

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['systemctl', 'reload', 'postgresql-9.6.service'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(db_cmd, err) = proc.communicate()

print (db_cmd)
```

I am trying to run systemctl reload postgresql-9.6.service using python 3 but I am not able to get output. And I am getting output such as:

reload: systemctl: command not found
b''

Comment: Do you have systemctl available?  Have you tried running the command directly on CLI to see if that works ?

Comment: @RohanGrover: yaah it is avaialble..thats y not understanding how to make it running here

Comment: Are you sure you executed your program with sudo?

Comment: @CarloFedericoVescovo: Yaah I added sudo also in order to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: read the docs: [Subprocess module Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).
You mistyped the import statement: it should be: "import subprocess".

Use sudo to execute the program you wrote: `sudo python /full/path/to/your/script`.

Then: it is more pythonic if you write `db_cmd = proc.communicate()[0]` because in this way you create only the variable you use.

Finally, your error is indicating that something went wrong while you were processing the systemctl command. In particular it seems to be missing the reload command. Try using restart.

In addition: this question is a duplicate of [How to use subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python).

Comment: It is subprocess...it was a typing mistake