# Find if the docker daemon is running

Tags: python

I need execute from the Python code to see if the docker` daemon is running OS independently.

Is it possible to achieve? Otherwise, it will be also okay to read the OS and execute for each platform individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was some linux system i would try to launch `systemctl status docker` to check of if service is running.

To make this platform independent you can make call to some docker function which needs docker daemon running like `docker ps`. It should return table of running processes when daemon is running otherwise it will show message:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is
>   the docker daemon running?

To launch this commands use Popen from subprocess library. About running commands and retrieving output you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python).

Comment: I needed to run it from the Python code (not terminal). I provided a solution which only work in Mac OS (atm). For the record, the `systemctl` is only works in linux/

Comment: Yes but you can run terminal command in python also. Read the ending of the answer carefully.

Comment: I didn't see the last line... sorry. But you could have provided a complete answer, though using the Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution where I check if the docker daemon is running using a bash script and if not, the python code will make it run.

`docker.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#!/bin/bash
#Open Docker, only if is not running
if (! docker stats --no-stream ); then
  # On Mac OS this would be the terminal command to launch Docker
  open /Applications/Docker.app
 #Wait until Docker daemon is running and has completed initialisation

while (! docker stats --no-stream ); do
  # Docker takes a few seconds to initialize
  echo "Waiting for Docker to launch..."
  sleep 1

echo "docker daemon is open for the local machine"
done
fi

#Start the Container.
```

Now check from the Python code and OS X if the daemon is running,

```
# check if the docker daemon is running in os x and if not run it
if(os.name == "posix"):
     subprocess.call("bin/docker.sh", shell=True)
```