# How to store executed command (of cmd) into a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried this:

```
import os
os.system('tree D://')
```

but it just executes my command. I can't store it into a variable.
What I'm going to do is to make a program that can tree a local (like C://) drive and search for specified file (it's like a local search engine).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use subprocess popen Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (for Python3.7+):

```
import subprocess
data = subprocess.run(["tree", "D://"], capture_output=True)
```

For Python<3.7:

```
import subprocess
data = subprocess.run(["tree", "D://"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['tree','D://'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

stdout should contain your command's output

Answer (score 1):

os.system is not the prefered way to fork or spawn a new process. for new process use the Popen. u can take a look at the python documentation here [subprocess_2.7_module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

```
import subprocess
command = "tree ...whatever"
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True) #shell=true cos you are running a win shell command

#if you need to communictae with the subprocess use pipes, see below:
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stderrret,stdoutret=p.communicate()
#now we can parse the output from the child process
str_command_out = parse_child_output(stdoutret) #we also need to check if child finish without failure!
do_what_ever_you_like_with(str_command_out)
```

Comment: i want to store the response of cmd (on my command) into a variabe.

Comment: please refer to the link i have wrote in my answer. you can do it with pipes! by parsing the process (child) output/stdoutput. you can do it with the return tuple value of communicate:
(stdout,stderr)=p.communictae()
hope that helps you further.
please vote up and accept my answer if you have found it a useful answer. thanks.