# How do I turn off Windows Defender in python

Tags: python, windows

I have an old computer that I want to try to remove Windows Defender on with a python script. I tried to use the command:

sc stop WinDefend

This command isn’t useful since it is used by the command prompt. Can someone show me?

Comment: you can execute windows commands through ["subprocess"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python)

Comment: Can this also be used for disabling/enabling firewall

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command using python like this;

```
import os

command = "sc stop WinDefend"

os.system(command)
```

Comment: Can this also be used for disabling/enabling firewall?