# python executing powershell script but no effect

Tags: python

```
  import subprocess

command = r"[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetFileDropList('E:\xampp\htdocs\tadiya\webpack.mix.js')"

result = subprocess.Popen(
    ["powershell.exe", command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = result.communicate()
print(stdout)
print(stderr)
```

### output

```
 b''
b"Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard].\r\nAt line:1 char:1\r\n+ [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetFileDropList('E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ta ...\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard:TypeName) [], RuntimeException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound\r\n \r\n"
```

script is running correctly.But while using on python  could'nt see any error did'nt work .what i wrong with it?

###### Expected Result:

script is just copy file to clipboard

nb: I could execute basic powershell commands like dir, other get-process,etc in this python code.

Comment: `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use subprocess popen Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python)

Comment: sorry that did'nt work

Comment: You need to add `.communicate()`

Comment: did .but now the error out put showing couldnt find the class of clipboard